remove time lock with yubikey
Ubuntu 23.10:
After 5 incorrect password entries, the entry is blocked for a certain period of time. I would like to be able to remove this time lock with the yubikey so that I can enter a password again immediately. The Yubikey should not log me in, but only remove the temporary lock.
The Yubikey is already registered, so logging in with the Yubikey would theoretically be possible.
What do I have to change in the /etc/pam.d/common-auth file and how and which files do I have to change?
